# A particular functor on the category of abelian groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

Is there a functor  $F$ from the category of abelian groups to itself such that for every non trivial group $G$, $F(G)$ can not be embedded in $G$?

**Edit:** According to the comment by Prof. Goodwillie I change the question as follows:

> Is there a functor $F$ on the category of infinite abelian groups which does not increase the cardinality of groups but for every infinite group $G$, the group $F(G)$ can not be embedded in $G$? By "Does not increase the cardinality" we mean $\text {Card}(F(G)) \leq  \text{Card}( G)$

Comment: Hint: First solve the problem for sets instead of abelian groups.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie  Thank you very much  for your comment and your hint. I am sorry if I  posted a non research question. According to your comment I try to improve it as follows. "Is there a  functor  $F$ on the category of infinite abelian groups which does not increase the cardinality but $F(G)$ can not be embedded in $G$?

Comment: It's again not research level, because for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there's an abelian group in which every abelian group of cardinal $\le\kappa$ embeds.

Comment: @YCor  what is that group for the countable case?

Comment: @YCor   According to your argument, do not we need that the universal group you pointed out has the same cardinality $k$? And is it always possible? Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28999/is-there-a-universal-countable-group-a-countable-group-containing-every-counta

Comment: Yes forgot to say "of the same cardinal". Such a group is $(\mathbf{Q}\oplus\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})^{(\kappa)}$.

Comment: @YCor but this group is not countable when k is countable.

Comment: Sure it's countable (countable direct sum of countable groups). $A^{(B)}$ denotes $\bigoplus_{b\in B}A$.

Comment: @YCor yes. I was thinking to direct product.

Comment: @YCor but please read the linked question and its answer.

Comment: I know this standard fact: for countable groups instead of countable abelian groups, the result fails. Have you got any particular reason to point me to this link?

Comment: @YCor I did not pay attention that   "Abelian"  is not included in  the linked question. So I wondered "is there a contradictory situation"?. So i sent you that link because i was surprised by that contradiction!!Any way sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @YCor so it seems that if I remove the word "Abelian"from my question then the question is nontrivial. Yes?

Comment: Possibly. Actually I don't know for uncountable groups: it a first step it might be better to first separately ask whether for some infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there exists a group of cardinal $\kappa$ in which every group of cardinal $\le\kappa$ embeds as a subgroup. (I just did an unsuccessful Google search).