How hard is the classification of finitely presented or generated simple groups?
The classification of finite simple groups took decades and tens of thousands of pages.
Question: Do we have any evidence about the difficulty of classifying either finitely presented simple groups or finitely generated simple groups (whichever seems easier)?
Certainly this is hopeless to do now, but I’m curious if the hopelessness is closer to “similar to finite simple groups, but way more detailed and longer” or “there is a hardness result that makes the problem computationally hard or wild” in a fundamentally different way to the finite case.

Are there countably many finitely generated simple groups?

There are uncountably many 2-generated simple groups, follows from Schupp’s theorem mentioned in this Q https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76646/infinite-2-generated-simple-group and Neumann’s theorem mentioned https://mathoverflow.net/a/29001/109573

It is an open problem to prove that the set of finitely presented simple groups is not computably enumerable. This would be implied by a positive solution to the Boone-Higman Conjecture.

Simplicity is a Markov property of finitely presented groups, so deciding if a finitely presented  group is simple is undecidable.
**Addendum: ** As pointed out in the comments, the Markov property does not indicate anything about the complexity of classifying finitely presented simple groups. One minor thing to note is that finitely presented simple groups have solvable word problem (see a hint at the above link). In turn, this implies that given two finite presentations of simple groups, one may determine if a homomorphism of the generators induces a homomorphism between the groups. So isomorphism between finite presentations of simple groups is recursive (this is true more generally for groups with solvable word problem). This doesn’t say much about the classification problem (eg whether fp simple groups are recursive), since we don’t know if there is a recursive procedure to generate finite presentations of simple groups (see Rauzy’s related comment above).
On the other hand, there is a fair amount of literature constructing finitely presented or generated infinite simple groups. One may take a finitely presented group without finite quotients, such as the Higman group, and take a quotient by a maximal normal subgroup. Then the quotient is a finitely generated infinite simple group. Other famous examples are due to Burger-Mozes,  Thompson, and Monod-Juschenko. There are also Tarski monsters and many variations with strange properties.

The first paragraph is great but doesn’t settle the question: I believe being abelian is also Markov and thus undecidable to detect, but still the finitely presented abelian groups can be classified.

@GeoffreyIrving Do you mean finitely presentable abelian groups or finitely presented abelian groups? I don't know exactly how "classification" is defined, but my first instinct would be that to "classify" finitely presented abelian groups, I would be handed an explicit finite presentation and have to decide what bucket to put it in. But maybe all I have to do is describe which abelian groups can arise?

Yes, that’s a reasonable distinction: I should have said presentable. I agree that classifying the abelian finite presentations themselves is impossible.

@GeoffreyIrving: I think you have a point. The classification of finitely generated abelian groups tells us that the class of finitely presented abelian groups is recursively enumerable (r.e.), while the fact that abelian-ness is a Markov property tells us that it's not co-r.e. So one might want the stronger statement that the class of finitely presented non-simple groups is Markov... Now I see this has been discussed above in the comments by Emmanuel Rauzy.

(Sorry, I briefly thought I had come up with a proof, but I had my positive and negative witnesses mixed up.)
