# Locally finite groups containing all finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Say that a group is **rich** if it contains isomorphic copies of all finite groups.

It is easy to produce rich groups, and also rich locally finite groups, for instance the restricted direct product $A=\bigoplus_{n\ge 5}\mathrm{Alt}_n$ of alternating groups. Also the group of finitely supported permutations of an infinite set is an example.

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433062/), which includes the observation that there is no rich group that embeds into every rich group. This question is an analogue, restricting to locally finite groups.

> **Main question.** is there a rich group that embeds into every rich *locally finite* group?

An equivalent question is:

> Does the above group $A$ embed into each rich locally finite group?

The equivalence between the two questions follows because every rich subgroup of $A$ contains a copy of $A$ (I can provide the simple argument upon request).

The specific family of alternating groups is not that important in this discussion, because if $(K_n)$ is a family of finite groups such that each finite group embeds in some $K_n$ and $K=\bigoplus K_n$, then $A$ and $K$ embed into each other.

A positive answer to the following would imply a positive answer to the main question:

> **Question 2.** Let $G$ be a rich locally finite group and $F$ a finite subgroup. Is the centralizer of $F$ rich?

*[Edit: Dave Benson proved that the answer is negative, see [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449893/14094). So this is not a helpful approach to Question 1.]*

For instance, if we restrict to locally finite FC-groups (i.e., locally finite groups in which every finite subgroup has a centralizer of finite index), we obtain that every rich locally finite FC-group contains a copy of $A$.

Regarding Question 2, I could find in the literature a number of papers proving results of the form "if a locally finite group has some finite subgroup with a small centralizer, then it has a somewhat constrained structure (in particular, is not rich)". I don't know whether Question 2 has been addressed in the above form.

Just for context, $\mathrm{PSL}_n$ of an infinite locally finite field is an example of a locally finite group with a finite subgroup with trivial centralizer. But it is not rich.

Comment: The paper "Subgroups of the Nottingham group" (Rachel Camina, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82495463.pdf) is an interesting and nonobvious example of related things (in the context of pro-$p$-groups).

Comment: When you define $A$, you mean it is a product of *alternating* groups, yes?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda typo fixed, thanks

Comment: It is equivalent to say that for each rich locally finite group $G$, and each finite group $F$, there is an embedding $F \to G$ whose centralizer is rich? (This is sufficient by the same proof as Question 2 implies Question 1 and necessary since every finite subgroup of the group of finitely supported permutations has this property). It is not obvious to me if this is true for $F =\mathbb Z/2$ so maybe that could be a start.

Answer (score 6):

For your question 2, there exists a locally finite group that is rich in your sense, and has a finite subgroup whose centraliser is trivial. If you look at my recent paper "Centralisers of finite groups in locally finite simple groups" https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2023.2217255, it gives examples of finite simple groups acting as outer automorphisms of the locally finite version of $SL(\infty,\mathbb{F}_q)$ with trivial fixed points. If you take the semidirect product, this gives a negative answer for your question. As an explicit example, take the semidirect product $SL(\infty,\mathbb{F}_9)\rtimes A_6$, with the subgroup $A_6$, but there are many other examples in my paper.

Comment: This is nice. A remark: for a group $G$, the existence of a finite subset whose centralizer is reduced to $Z(G)$ can be interpreted as: the closure $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is discrete (in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, endowed with the Onofri topology of pointwise convergence). For $G$ countable, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a Polish group. It is an open question whether there exists $G$ infinite countable locally finite such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is countable. A necessary condition for this is indeed that $\overline{\mathrm{Inn}(G)}$ is discrete, which is already a strong condition.